# Report viewer control showing header bar but not the report

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2016

I have a report viewer control in my web application project which is trying to render some rdlc reports. When I run my application a browser window (IE11) opens and shows a report viewer control Menu/Header (See screenshot below). I click the 'floppy disk icon' to save as a PDF. The PDF looks perfect.  I want the report to be shown in the report viewer. Any thoughts?

[image: Report viewer not rendering report]

I am running:

- IE 11
- solution is targeting .Net 4.5.2
- SQL Server 2016

I have tried the following so far with no luck:

- Added `localhost` to IE "Compatibility View"
- Changed the config file as per the last post in the below link:
  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f07087b-ff38-4c3d-943f-80d56a6da369/2010-reportviewer-control-not-rendering-in-internet-explorer-when-sizetoreportcontent-false?forum=vsreportcontrols
- Changed the config file as per the marked answer (AsyncRendering was throwing exception so not added) in the below link:
  [ReportViewer control not displaying reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575351/reportviewer-control-not-displaying-reports)
- Updated the assemblies as per the below link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started

Comment: Does it show properly in chrome?

Comment: Good point, not sure if chrome is installed or we can use chrome on our final install. But it is worth a try, i will update you in a mo!

Comment: @DanielB - I have installed chrome and set it as default browser. The page never loads. I have a breakpoint at page_load and it never even hits the breakpoint. It has been running for about 3 mins now.

Comment: @DanielB - Finally the page loaded in chrome and breakpoints were hit. However I still get the same problem. If saved the PDF looks perfect but no report is shown in the report viewer.

Comment: not easy to simulate yr environment. did u try https://forums.asp.net/t/1990665.aspx?Report+viewer+is+not+showing+out+put+report+in+IE11+

Comment: did u chk html source code to see whether anything rendered?